# Finding Values Present in Two or More Unequal-Length Vectors

Tags: r

I have the following two numeric vectors:

```
A <- c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
B <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 13)
```

I want to generate a new vector `C` that contains the values that are present in both `A` and `B` (not the positions at which these values are found). The result should be:

```
C <- c(3, 5)
```

I also want to generate a vector `D` containing the values present in `A` but not present in `B` and a vector `E` containing the values present in `B` but not `A`.

```
D <- c(1, 7, 9)
E <- c(2, 4, 6, 10, 12, 13)
```

What is the best way to do this using base R? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the base R function `intersect()`.

In addition, generally speaking I wouldn't use `C` as a variable name as it really close to `c()`, which might cause you problems.

```
A <- c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
B <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 13)

Inter <- intersect(A, B)

[1] 3 5
```

For the opposite of `intersect()':

```
#taken from here:https://www.r-bloggers.com/outersect-the-opposite-of-rs-intersect-function/
outersect <- function(x, y) {
  sort(c(setdiff(x, y),
         setdiff(y, x)))
}

outersect(A, B)
[1]  1  2  4  6  7  9 10 12 13
```

Comment: Thanks! I just edited my original question - how would I create vectors `D` and `E` (see above)?

Comment: @DavidMoore `setdiff(A, B)` and `setdiff(B, A)`

Answer (score 0):

```
A <- c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
B <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 13)
C <- A[!A%in%B]
D <- B[!B%in%A]
```

Which yields

```
> C
[1] 1 7 9
> D
[1]  2  4  6 10 12 13
```